# Call a member function of a class inside JSON object in a shorter way

Tags: javascript, json, function, class, object

My code is as follows,

```js
class myClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.memberVar1="";
        this.memberVar2="";
    }

    memberFunction1()
    {
        // memberFunction1 code
    }
}

var myObj = {
    objVar1 : someJsonObject,
    objVar2 : new myClass()
}
```

Instead of calling the memberFunction and memberVar1,memberVar2 like

```js
myObj.objVar2.memberVar1;
myObj.objVar2.memberFunction1();
```

I wish to call them as follows

```js
myObj.memberVar1;
myObj.memberFunction1();
```

Is there any way i can restructure `myObj` to achieve this ?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You can use `Object.create()`, but it seems more like you want to create another class what `extends` `myClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first class objects in Javascript, and a member of a Javascript class is just an object, so there's nothing stopping you setting the reference that `myObj.memberFunction1` to whatever you like, including `someJsonObject.memberFunction1`, however you need to be aware that the behavior of `this` will be different depending on how you set the reference.  This may be important to make your `memberFunction` behave correctly depending on context.

```js
class myClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.memberVar1="";
        this.memberVar2="";
    }

    memberFunction1()
    {
        // memberFunction1 code
    }
}

let someJsonObject = {
    memberFunction1: function(source) {
        if (this === myObj) { console.log(`${source}: "this" is myObj`) }
        else if (this === someJsonObject) { console.log(`${source}: "this" is someJsonObject`) }
        else { console.log('JavaScript interpreter is insane') }
    }
}

var myObj = {
    objVar1 : someJsonObject,
    objVar2 : new myClass(),
    memberFunction1: someJsonObject.memberFunction1 // the assignment will cause "this" to point to myObj

}


console.log('==== setting the reference (changes this) ====')
myObj.memberFunction1('myObj')
someJsonObject.memberFunction1('someJsonObject')
myObj.objVar1.memberFunction1('myObj.objVar1') // myObj.objVar1 is === someJsonObject
myObj.keepThis = myObj.memberFunction1 // You can hang onto the "myObj" referenced version of the function if you want
console.log('==== binding to someJsonObject ====')
myObj.memberFunction1 = myObj.memberFunction1.bind(someJsonObject) // using bind will make "this" point to whatever you like (i.e someJsonObject)
myObj.memberFunction1('myObj')
someJsonObject.memberFunction1('someJsonObject')
myObj.objVar1.memberFunction1('myObj.objVar1')
myObj.keepThis('myObj.keepThis')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
const someObj = new myClass();

var myObj = {
    objVar1 : {},
    memberFunction1 : someObj.memberFunction1
}
```

Then call it like you want:

```
myObj.memberFunction1()
```

EDIT:

If you want to merge N number of members you can use Object.create like this:

```
const instance = new myClass();
const myObj = Object.create(instance);
myObj.memberFunction1()
```

Comment: I wish to call N different memberFunctions and memberVariables and it is not feasible to create a key for everyone of them

Comment: @Pervez check my updated answer